# Regenerate SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, certificates

Recently I'm dealing with a RHEL 7.8 host's Tenable Nessus Plugin #51192 issue which is "SSL Certificate Cannot Be Trusted".

The Tenable Nessus report said this vulnerability was caused by "www" service via TCP port 8443, 8444 and 9100

So I got the output of "netstat -tulnp" from this host and found the following programs utilizing TCP ports mentioned above:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25514/openshift
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8444            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      85402/openshift
tcp6       0      0 :::9100                 :::*                    LISTEN      3028/kube-rbac-prox
```

Additionally, I examined theses programs via "ps" command and acquired the following details:

```
   PID TTY      STAT   TIME   COMMAND
25514 ?        Ssl  47024:19 openshift start master api --config=/etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml --loglevel=2
85402 ?        Ssl  752:23 openshift start master controllers --config=/etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml --listen=https://0.0.0.0:8444 --loglevel=2
3028 ?        Ssl   10:14 /usr/bin/kube-rbac-proxy --secure-listen-address=:9100 --upstream=http://127.0.0.1:9101/ --tls-cert-file=/etc/tls/private/tls.crt --tls-private-key-fil
```

It seemed that theses openshift or k8s stuff are utilizing web services that have incorrect SSL certificates.

Just want to clarify which targets are the correct ones to fix this plugin #51192 SSL certificate. Should the fix be done only to the web SSL certificate?
(not so sure about how this would impact the production services that are utilizing openshift/k8s web.)

Comment: The listed processes are from Red Hat OpenShift, which is a variant of Kubernetes. OpenShift uses self-generated certificates to secure communications between its internal components, and this is being flagged by the Nessus plugin. You'll need to work with your K8s admin to sort this out, because there's a fair bit of complexity involved.

Comment: @Haxiel thanks for the help!! I'll discuss this with the administrators.